# Is it possible to call activity and fragment both simultaneously from another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-framelayout

I want to set a default frame layout on fragment,and this frame layout shows at top of the half layout,and remaining half contains list view.frame layout updates the layout item when click on the list item these all work fine.But when I want to set default frame layout when comes from previous activity then it creates problem.Here is how i am opening my fragments and this is my adapter class from this activity. I want to set the default frame layout on next activity containing list.

```
 grid.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View arg0) {
     // Get the position
     resultp = data.get(position);
     frame=(FrameLayout)grid.findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
     Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);

     intent.putExtra("id", resultp.get(MainActivity.RANK));

     intent.putExtra("count", resultp.get(MainActivity.COUNTRY));

     intent.putExtra("population",resultp.get(MainActivity.POPULATION));

     intent.putExtra("flag", resultp.get(MainActivity.FLAG));
     // Start SingleItemView Class

     intent.putExtra("mylist", data);
     context.startActivity(intent);


     if(frame==null){

        DefaultLogFrag fragment1 = new DefaultLogFrag();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager1 = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction1 = fragmentManager1.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction1.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment1);
        fragmentTransaction1.commit();
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: You should add the fragment in `onCreate()` method of the `SingleItemView` Activity

Answer (score 0):

Just Open your next activity using

`Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);`

And add the Fragment transaction in `onCreate()` of `SingleItemView.java` activity

If you want to add different Fragments based on some condition then you can pass conditional variables with intent `intent` variable extra :

```
intent.putExtra("whichFragment", /* integer parameter */ 4);
```

Handle them in `onCreate()` of `SingleItemView.java` :

```
switch(getIntent().getExtraString("whichFragment")) {
    case 1: /* add Fragment 1 */
        break;
    case 2: /* add Fragment 2 */
        break;
    case 3: /* add Fragment 3 */
        break;
    case 4: /* add Fragment 4 */
        break;
}
```